# Ant script with dependencies

Tags: ant

I have a project in Java EE that includes classes from other project .
I tried adding the classes that are used in this project directly.
These classes are created in the folder with a javac command just before the javac for the module which I am trying to build.

When I looked at the error the error contains the classes in  CTDUtility.bin path.
How can I get it done?

```
    <fileset dir="${CTDUtility.bin}">
        <include name="**/*.class"/>
    </fileset>
```

```
    </javac>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When defining the classpath, you only need to provide the directory containing the classes, not the class files themselves.

e.g.

```
<path id="compile.classpath">
     <pathelement location="${CTDUtility.bin}" />
</path>
```